# A model (Poisson GLM) has a higher pseudo-R2 yet a larger AIC comparing to an alternative model (negative binomial GLM)?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, aic, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I used negative binomial GLM and Poisson GLM on a count data, the Poisson has a higher deviance-based pseudo-$R^2$, yet a larger AIC?! Can anybody explain why this happen while normally higher $R^2$ should have lower AIC?

***negative binomial GLM***
[image: nb results]

***Poisson GLM***
[image: p results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the answer in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122063/81865). To cite the answer in there

> The key point is that with `glm.nb()` the reported null deviance is
>   conditional upon the estimated value of $\theta$.

So the denominator you use in the two pseudo-$R^2$ differs. Since the original pseudo-$R^2$ is defined as $1 - \frac{LR_{\text{Full}}}{LR_{\text{NULL}}}$ then I figure one could re-estimate $\theta$ for the null model. I.e., do something like the following (example from `?glm.nb`)

```
> #####
> # show that we are in roughly the same situation
> library(MASS)
> f1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine)
> AIC(f1)
[1] 1093.025
> 1 - f1$deviance / f1$null.deviance
[1] 0.2856732
> 
> # fit with glm
> f2 <- glm(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn), data = quine, family = )
> AIC(f2)
[1] 1207.964
> 1 - f2$deviance / f2$null.deviance
[1] 0.2877621
> 
> # Compute R^2 with re-estimation of models and likelihoods
> f1_null <- update(f1, . ~ 1  - .)
> f1$null.deviance == f1_null$deviance # for illustration
[1] FALSE
> c(1 - logLik(f1) / logLik(f1_null))  # drop class 
[1] 0.0493996
> 
> f2_null <- update(f2, . ~ 1 - .)
> f2_null$deviance == f2$null.deviance # for illustration
[1] TRUE
> c(1 - logLik(f2) / logLik(f2_null))  # drop class
[1] 0.04036157
```

Though the above raises the question why the pseudo-$R^2$ differs in the latter case with the `glm` fit. It should not according to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/273208/81865) and the definitions of diviance? Further, I do not know whether comparing the pseudo-$R^2$ in the last example is correct.