# How to calculate the percentage deviance explained wiith glm.nb?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, deviance

I’ve observed that when I fit a Negative Binomial regression with `glm.nb`, the null deviance I get from the model differs from the deviance of the null model. I think this is because both models estimate the parameter theta of the Negative Binomial model in different ways. See

> Gavin Simpson (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1390/gavin-simpson), Why does the null deviance in `glm.nb` differ between models of the same response variable?, URL (version: 2014-10-30): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122063.

My question now is how should I compute the percentage deviance explained of a model, using the null deviance I get from it or using the deviance of the null model?

Here is an example:

```
model <- glm.nb(Behaviors ~ Parasitism, data = my_data)
null_model <- glm.nb(Behaviors ~ 1, data = my_data)
model$deviance
## [1] 164.2626
model$null.deviance
## [1] 167.64
null_model$deviance
## [1] 164.396
```

In this setting, the deviance of my model is 164.2626, but what is the percentage deviance explained?

$$100 \left( \frac{167.64 - 164.2626}{167.64} \right) = 2.01$$

or

$$100 \left( \frac{164.396 - 164.2626}{164.396} \right) = 0.08$$

I’ve included a `dput()` of my data set below to allow for replication.

```
structure(list(Parasitism = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Behaviors = c(1L, 8L, 3L, 13L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
    9L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 
    21L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 10L, 
    23L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 17L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    27L, 19L, 5L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 19L, 12L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 
    3L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 26L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 27L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 
    4L, 7L, 16L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 24L, 25L, 17L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
    8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-156L))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to late, but I am answering here if someone else require answer:

The answer is your first one (i.e., 2.01). Anyone can easily calculate percent deviance explained of a model by the following codes:

```
100*with(summary(model), 1 - deviance/null.deviance)
```